# Facing issue in Play store

Tags: android

I have uploaded my app in the google play store,when I tried to install the app from the play store I can see option like uninstall and update , I couldn’t find the option for install.

Comment: You are probably using the same phone for development

Comment: that means you have already installed it. Probably from ANdroid Studio

Comment: Go to `Settings>Apps>YourApp>Unistall for all users` . Then check .

Answer (score 0):

that means the same application is already installed in your device.

Comment: No this is the first time I am trying to install the app in my mobile